# Updating address for UK licence

Tags: united-kingdom, driving-license

I'm applying for changing the address in my driving licence. I'm filling right now the D1 Form, following the guidelines provided [here](https://www.gov.uk/change-address-driving-licence/apply-by-post), the form is the one below

[image]

I don't have to change either name or photo. The only bit concerning me is the payment (in "your checklist" section). Do I need to pay anything for this application.

It doesn't seem to me from the guideline above, but I'm just checking.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no charge to change the address on your driving licence

https://www.gov.uk/change-address-driving-licence

It's a legal requirement to tell DVLA when you change address and any charge would put some people off doing that. Making it a free service encourages compliance.

Comment: Should I just leave it blank then?

Comment: Yes. But just one more thing. Do you already have a photo card licence or do you have a legacy paper only licence? If the latter, you'll need to move to the newer format and there might be a fee for that.

Comment: Already have photocard one.

Comment: I forgot to ask this, do I need to send the licence as well together with the application? It seems to me I have to send it only If I wanted to change picture on the licence, though given we are talking about "changing" not sure what to do.